# it was/it were + plural noun

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, subjects, clefts

Which of the following is correct?

1. It **was** the memories he made that mattered.
2. It **were** the memories he made that mattered.

Comment: See also: [Were or was, and why?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/266742)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since "it" is singular, here "was" seems more appropriate.
So the right sentence would be:

> It was the memories he made that mattered.

"were" is used with singular nouns/pronouns only when the sentence is in the SUBJUNCTIVE mood which is used for hypothetical situations. For example:

> If I were you, .....